# Cardview width not matching parent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cardview

I need to create a Recyclerview. For that I have created an cardview model to be displayed in a recyclerview. Even though i have given match parent to the layouts, the width of cardview is not fitting the parent. Its width is showing approximately up to half of the screen(not matching parent)  Do anyone can support?.please advise better way to do this.

Attached the xml code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/border_creatives"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="6dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/dficon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline19"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline23"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline18"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline50"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amiko_semibold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline24"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ddownbutton"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline50"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline18" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ddate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amiko_semibold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline50"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dfileextension"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amiko_semibold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier7"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline24" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ddownbutton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mins_customselector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/filedownload_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline22"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline18"
                android:focusable="true" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8275" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.045" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.57" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="right"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="ddate" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

main layout having recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Download_Activity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline49"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/toolbar">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/downloads"
        android:textColor="#FCFFFD"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/carter_one"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drecyclerdownloads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline49"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter class

```
public class DownloadsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Downloadsviewholder> {

    Download_Activity download_activity;
    ArrayList<Downloadsmodel> downloadsmodels;



    public DownloadsAdapter(Download_Activity download_activity, ArrayList<Downloadsmodel> downloadsmodels) {
        this.download_activity = download_activity;
        this.downloadsmodels = downloadsmodels;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Downloadsviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(download_activity.getBaseContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.downloads_elements,null,false);
        return new Downloadsviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Downloadsviewholder downloadsviewholder, final int i) {
        downloadsviewholder.dName.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getName());
        downloadsviewholder.dUploaddate.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getUploaddate());
        downloadsviewholder.dExtension.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension());
        Picasso.get().load(downloadsmodels.get(i).getIcon()).into(downloadsviewholder.dIcon);
        downloadsviewholder.dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ConnectionCheck.checkconnetion(download_activity.getBaseContext())) {
                    dowloadFile(downloadsviewholder.dName.getContext(), downloadsmodels.get(i).getName(), downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension()
                            , DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, downloadsmodels.get(i).getLink());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(download_activity.getBaseContext(),"Check your internet connection",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void dowloadFile (Context context,String filename, String fileextension, String destinationdirectory, String url){

        DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationdirectory, filename+"."+fileextension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return downloadsmodels.size();
    }
}
```

Viewholder

```
public class Downloadsviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView dName;TextView dLink;TextView dUploaddate; TextView dExtension;
    ImageView dIcon;
    ImageButton dButton;

    public Downloadsviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        dName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dname);
       dUploaddate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ddate);
       dExtension=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dfileextension);
        dButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ddownbutton);
        dIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dficon);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your `Adapter` class.

Comment: What's the size of `@drawable/border_creatives`???

Comment: You've provided layout of item. Please also provide layout that has the RecyclerView as your item layout seems to be just fine.

Comment: I guess you might have set your recycler view width to wrap content or some specific width change it to match_parent

Comment: @ror its posted

Comment: @AgentP its set to match parent

Comment: @FlyingDutchman      border creatives <shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#B1AFAF" /> <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/> </shape>

Comment: Post your adapter code too

Comment: Change the `inflate()` call in `onCreateViewHolder()` to `inflate(R.layout.downloads_elements, parent, false)`. I would also mention that you do not want to use `getBaseContext()` for the `LayoutInflater`. Just use the `Activity` itself; otherwise, your items won't have the appropriate themes and styles applied.

Comment: @AgentP  it is posted

Comment: @MikeM. Width is getting to match parent now. But only one item is showing in Recyclerview

Comment: Change the root `<LinearLayout>`'s `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Actually, that `<LinearLayout>` is rather pointless if it's only ever going to have one child. You could get rid of that, and just make the `<CardView>` the root.

Comment: @MikeM.   Ok. thanks a lot. Its working fine now